# Why OSL script is not showing the result?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, osl

I tried to copy the source of the *Separate RGB* shader but not getting the same result as the original Separate RGB node.

- Top Left: A copy of Separate RGB source taken from blender repo.
- Top Right: The texture used as mask.
- Bottom Left: Plane with material using the the script to get the B channel.
- Bottom Right: Plane with material using the original Separate RGB node to get the B channel.

Why is it not working using the script?

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled Open Shading Language in your Render options?

Comment: That is it. I thought that's the default since the built-in shaders have . osl extension. The result does not show in material view mode though; it needs to be rendered. Thanks.

Comment: The material view actually tries to convert the cycles materials to OpenGL in the background, and use that in the viewport. It cannot do that for OSL nodes sadly.

Comment: note that GPU can't handle script nodes :/ (the "Open Shading Language" option does not shows up)